# Render a "ghost" object that receives environmental lights but doesn't contribute

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lighting

Let's say I have a scene like the "Cornell box" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornell_box). If I add a white sphere in there, it will:

- Receive bounce lighting from the walls and other objects in the scene, so you can see a reflection of the environment on the white sphere
- Reflect incoming rays onto the nearby walls and objects in the scene, so you could see a reflection of the sphere on other surfaces
- Cast a shadow

What I'm trying to achieve is the first bullet, but not the second or third. I basically need the sphere to appear as part of the scene, but without affecting the lighting in any way.

Is there an easy way to do this with Cycles?

Comment: If you're talking about Cycles, you shluld be able to set these things in the Properties panel > Object > Visibility > Ray Visibility

Comment: I think using is camera ray to select your object's shader over a transparent one should do the trick if I understand your objective correctly